# Android: layout does not appear as tab content

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I have some tabs based on layouts with their own xml description, but when i tried to set tab content i got such a result:

http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/1787/appnavihist.jpg

(white field with text is a part of home.xml layout). Here's some code:

```
    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home").setContent(R.id.LinearLayout_home);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_root" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/home"/>
    </FrameLayout>      

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code looks ok. Can post contents of xml layouts?

Comment: sure.. (main) http://pastie.org/1263646 (home) http://pastie.org/1263648

Comment: Next time try to paste all related stuff directly to stackoverflow to make it easier for other users to find the truth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with layout that contains tabwidget element, try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` property to the tabwidget container:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_root" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Default android template for TabActivity looks like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I guess it should work for you as well.

Comment: Added default android platform implementation as example.

Answer (score 0):

its working..
i did try..

```
 <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </TabWidget>
```

but i get xactly which my requirement with this

```
  <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>
```

[ to remove extra space below of tabhost]